# How to set global attribute if there is a ajax listener

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

```
  <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="m_no"  value="#{currentevent.mmlno}" update=":trtInfoForm:datapanel" rendered="#{currentevent.mmlno == false and currentevent.mmlyes == false}" >
     <f:ajax listener="#{currentevent.changeNoVal}" render="@form" />
  </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

How to set global attribute for the above component, so that it doesn't link up with ajaxStatus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `p:ajax` rather than `f:ajax` and you can set the global attribute of that.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="m_no"  value="#{currentevent.mmlno}" update=":trtInfoForm:datapanel" rendered="#{currentevent.mmlno == false and currentevent.mmlyes == false}" >
    <p:ajax listener="#{currentevent.changeNoVal}" update="@form" global="false"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```